# Dealing with "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Provided address [object Promise] is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed"

Tags: web3js, javascript, addresses, frontend

I'm, trying to connect a front-end to my smart contract but whenever I call the function from the UI I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: 
Provided address [object Promise] is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted.
```

I'm completely lost. I guess this has something to do with the contract address but I'm not sure what I did wrong. Other answers regarding this error didn't help me.
Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var abi = contractAbi;
        var address = "0x773e94b3394913FD7D1562ADf21A2D8e0720c38F";


        async function loadWeb3() {
            if (window.ethereum) {
                window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
                window.ethereum.enable();
                

            }
        }

        async function loadContract(){
            return await new window.web3.eth.Contract(abi,address);
        }

        async function load() {
            await loadWeb3();
            window.contract = await loadContract();
        }

        async function getCurrentAccount() {
            const accounts = await window.web3.eth.getAccounts();
            return accounts[0];

        }

        async function listNFT(){
            var buyerAddress = document.getElementById('buyer-address').value;
            var tokenId = document.getElementById('sell-tokenId').value;
            var price = document.getElementById('selling-price').value;
            const account = getCurrentAccount();
            await window.contract.methods.listNFT(buyerAddress,price,tokenId).send({from: account, value:100000});
            
        }

        async function buy(){
            var sellerAddress = document.getElementById('seller-address').value;
            var tokenId = document.getElementById('tokenId').value;
            var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
            const account = await getCurrentAccount();
            await window.contract.methods.buy(sellerAddress,tokenId,price).send({from: account});

            

        }

        load();

    </script>
```

Any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an `await` when calling `getCurrentAccount`

Answer (score 0):

that error is due to some changes in recent update of ethers package, so you have to go back to previous packages of ethers
to do that :

1. npm uninstall ethers
2. npm i -S ethers@5.7.2